# Adding FavIcon to Sharepoint 2013 Site

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When we upgraded from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013, our favicon was no longer being displayed.  An internet search offered a couple of solutions.  One method suggested placing the file in C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES and performing an IIS reset.

Not having access to the server and not wanting to disrupt a production site with an IIS reset, I opted to handle this with an upload to a site library and master page change.

I found the following to be an easy change to make.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I took:

1. Upload your .ico file to your site / siteassets library
2. Make note of the URL to the uploaded .ico file (right click and choose copy shortcut from the menu
   [image: copy example]
3. In Sharepoint Designer, open your master page file - v4.master or your custom file
4. Search for this line: *SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon..*  (if you have a custom master page and this line is missing, copy it from v4.master and place it in the head section.)
5. Paste the URL of your .ico file from step two into the SPShortcutIcon element on the IconUrl property
   [image: path]
6. Save, checkin, and approve your master page.  That's it.  Your .ico file will appear in browser tabs and in the URL address bar depending on your browser.  If using IE, you may need to clear your cache to get it to display.